# CSS calc() not working for centring the td element

Tags: html, css, css-calc

I want to create a table, the second column (which is represented by a single cell) is put in the center of a page. I am trying to use calc() function in order to do that, however it does not work. Here is my code:

```css
.bio {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

img {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="20">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="image of me">
    </td>
    <td class="bio">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using a table element?

Comment: Tables should not be used for layout unless you are making an email template - this looks like it is layout, in which case you should use css instead.

Comment: but if you insist on using a table, you just need to give the first column a width of 200px, take the width off the second column and add a width of 100% to the table (if I'm understanding your problem correctly)

Comment: Turnip and Pete,
Thank you for your suggestions. What I am doing is an exercise (which also shows how the pages were structured before the CSS), and I wanted to modify the layout a bit, so yes, I insist on using tables.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="20">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="image of me">
    </td>
    <td class="bio">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```